# rsyslog change timestamp format for specifix filter

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

I wish to change my rsyslog timestamp format to RFC-3339 of specific log file (msg).

I have the following file `/etc/rsyslog.d/10-zn.conf`
with the following content:

```
:msg, contains, "my_prefix"       /var/log/zn.log
```

which means that save to /var/log/zn.log all of the lines which contains "my_prefix".

I wish to change the timestamp from RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat which is %b %d %H:%M:%S
to RFC-3339 but I can find out how to do it just for the logs which contains my prefix, is there any way to do it?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the right configuration

```
if $msg contains '{{my_prefix}}' then { 
        action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/zn.log" template="RSYSLOG_FileFormat")
}
```

[RSYSLOG_FileFormat](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/templates.html) template already come with RFC3339 timestamp